# Delegate method not being triggered by selector

Tags: ios, swift3, delegates, protocols, selector

I'm passing in a selector from Class A to a method in Class B to ultimately trigger a delegate method, `PressedButtonForMethodA` from Class A.  But, I think I have something wrong with my selector because neither the delegate method or ClassB's `PressedButtonForMethodA()` (ClassB.PressedButtonForMethodA() is just for debugging purposes) are being executed.  Using Swift 3 and NO storyboards.  Here's what I have in the swift playground:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class classA: UIViewController, ClassBDelegate {
    private func setNavbarButtons() {
        let myBarButton = classB()
        myBarButton.delegate = self
        let myBarButtonItem = myBarButton.setup("Press This", #selector(PressedButtonForMethodA))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = myBarButtonItem
    }

    func PressedButtonForMethodA() {
        NSLog("Method A in Class A fired!") // <<--THIS METHOD NOT BEING CALLED
    }
}

protocol ClassBDelegate {
    func PressedButtonForMethodA()
}

class classB: UIView {
    var delegate: ClassBDelegate?
    func setup(_ title: String, _ selectorAction: Selector) -> UIBarButtonItem {

        let shadow = NSShadow()
        shadow.shadowColor = UIColor.clear

        let attributesNormal = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white,
            NSShadowAttributeName : shadow,
            NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12.0)
        ]

        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        let buttonTitleAttributesNormal = NSAttributedString(string: title,
                                                             attributes: attributesNormal)
        button.setAttributedTitle(buttonTitleAttributesNormal, for: UIControlState.normal)
        let buttonTextSize = button.intrinsicContentSize
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: buttonTextSize.width, height: buttonTextSize.height)

        button.addTarget(self, action: selectorAction, for: .touchUpInside)
        let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)

        return barButtonItem
    }

    func PressedButtonForMethodA() {
        NSLog("Method A in Class B fired!")  // <<-- THIS METHOD NOT FIRED EITHER
        delegate?.PressedButtonForMethodA()
    }
}
```

Comment: Much easier to help you if you post your actual code - or, at least enough of it that it can be used and tested...

Comment: Good point, DonMag.  Just updated to include the actual code that I have in the swift playground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Complete Edit:**

I put some more thought into this, and played around with a couple ways of doing it and came up with two reasonable options. Not sure if either method would be considered "better," but I guess I'd lean toward Method #1. I think it is more self-contained, and doesn't require Delegate conforming. (Ignore my other answer, if you've seen it... I'm combining both into one).

**Method #1**

classB is a UIBarButtonItem subclass. Call setup() passing the title, the Selector/Action (a func inside self), and a reference to self (which will be used as the target of the button Action).

```
class ClassAB: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setNavbarButtons()
    }

    private func setNavbarButtons() {

        let myBarButton = classB()

        myBarButton.setup("Press Me AB", #selector(ClassAB.PressedButtonForMethodAB), self)

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = myBarButton

    }

    func PressedButtonForMethodAB() {
        NSLog("Method AB in Class AB fired!")
    }

}

class classB: UIBarButtonItem {

    func setup(_ title: String, _ selectorAction: Selector, _ target: Any) {

        let shadow = NSShadow()
        shadow.shadowColor = UIColor.clear

        let attributesNormal = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white,
            NSShadowAttributeName : shadow,
            NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12.0)
        ]

        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        let buttonTitleAttributesNormal = NSAttributedString(string: title, attributes: attributesNormal)
        button.setAttributedTitle(buttonTitleAttributesNormal, for: UIControlState.normal)
        let buttonTextSize = button.intrinsicContentSize
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: buttonTextSize.width, height: buttonTextSize.height)

        // my navbar is white...
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        // target and action both assigned by the creator (in this case, ClassAB)
        button.addTarget(target, action: selectorAction, for: .touchUpInside)

        customView = button

    }

}
```

---

**Method #2**

classC is a UIBarButtonItem subclass. Call setup() passing the title, and assign self as the delegate of classC. Inside classC, the button Action is a class-level func, which in turn calls a defined delegate function.

```
class ClassAC: UIViewController, ClassCDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setNavbarButtons()
    }

    private func setNavbarButtons() {

        let myBarButton = classC()

        myBarButton.setup("Press Me AC")

        myBarButton.delegate = self

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = myBarButton

    }

    func PressedButtonForMethodAC() {
        NSLog("Method AC in Class AC fired!")
    }
}

protocol ClassCDelegate {
    func PressedButtonForMethodAC()
}

class classC: UIBarButtonItem {

    var delegate: ClassCDelegate?

    func setup(_ title: String) {

        let shadow = NSShadow()
        shadow.shadowColor = UIColor.clear

        let attributesNormal = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white,
            NSShadowAttributeName : shadow,
            NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12.0)
        ]

        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        let buttonTitleAttributesNormal = NSAttributedString(string: title, attributes: attributesNormal)
        button.setAttributedTitle(buttonTitleAttributesNormal, for: UIControlState.normal)
        let buttonTextSize = button.intrinsicContentSize
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: buttonTextSize.width, height: buttonTextSize.height)

        // my navbar is white...
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        // target is self, selector action is inside self... *that* is where we'll call back to the delegate
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(classC.classCTap), for: .touchUpInside)

        customView = button

    }

    func classCTap() {
        NSLog("tap inside ClassC ... call back to delegate method")
        delegate?.PressedButtonForMethodAC()
    }

}
```

Comment: Method 2 is a great call... Still getting used to Swift and def should have subclassed Class B (or Class C in your solution) from UIBarButtonView. Ultimately, since my goal was to trigger ClassA.PressedButtonForMethodA(), I ended up changing the target property of button.addTarget(self, action: selectorAction, for: touchUpInside) from self to delegate which fixed the problem. And, your solution of changing the parent class of Class C would trigger that method in both classes. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

```
let myBarButtonItem = myBarButton.setup("Press This", #selector(PressedButtonForMethodA))
```

should be

```
let myBarButtonItem = myBarButton.setup("Press This", #selector(myBarButton.PressedButtonForMethodA))
```

In the set up method, you are passing the selector from ClassA when you should be passing the selector from ClassB because you added `self` as the target here:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: selectorAction, for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: right, Johnslay.  I'm wondering why the selectorAction isn't calling `delegate?.PressedButtonForMethodA()`  What would the syntax look like to get the selector in Class A to call that method?  I was trying to get class B's PressedButtonForMethodA() to fire just as another way of getting this functionality to work but obviously, that was firing either.

Comment: Oh I didn't see that, but you're passing a selector from ClassA and trying to call the selector from ClassB because you set the target to Self on the button

Comment: hey man - thanks for the help.  Your explanation at the end about using `self` as the target is what helped me figure out that I needed to pass in `delegate` to trigger the method in Class A.  But, I chose the solution from @donmag since it ultimately explained more of the issue (Class B was inheriting from the wrong superclass).  Thanks again!

Comment: NP, I recommend using a delegate pattern and keeping your button's action contained to self. If you pass a selector from another class, bad things can happen and cause a crash.